# C++ Inheritance "No Viable Conversion" Error

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong? I am making the object in my main and trying to pass a string variable to its setter. I keep getting the same error "No viable conversion"

```
#define PatientType_hpp
#include "PersonType.hpp"
#include "DoctorType.hpp"
#include "dataType.hpp"

class PatientType : public PersonType
{

private:
  DoctorType drName;

public:
  DoctorType getDrName() const;

  void setDrName(DoctorType);
};

#endif /* PatientType_hpp */
```

---

```
//setters and getters

DoctorType PatientType::getDrName() const { 
  return drName;
}

void PatientType::setDrName(DoctorType drName) {
  this->drName = drName;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef DoctorType_hpp
#define DoctorType_hpp
#include "PersonType.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
    class DoctorType: public PersonType
{
private:

    string drSpecialty;


public:

        string getDrSpecialty()const;
        void setDRSpecialty(string);

};
#endif /* DoctorType_hpp */
```

---

```
#include "DoctorType.hpp"
#include <iostream>

    string DoctorType::getDrSpecialty()const
{
        return drSpecialty;

}
    void DoctorType::setDRSpecialty(string drSpecialty)
{
        this->drSpecialty=drSpecialty;
```

### }

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  PatientType example;

  string drName = "Mr.Scott";

  example.setDrName(drName);
  // ERROR No viable conversion from 'std::__1::string aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>,     allocator<char> >') to 'DoctorType'
}
```

I'm expecting for it to compile because I am passing in a string into the Patient type which i think accepts strings.

Comment: I think the error message sums up the issue: `void PatientType::setDrName(DoctorType drName)` expects object of `DoctorType` and you are passing `std::string`

Comment: Why do you expect it to compile? `drName` is a `std::string` and `setDrName` expects a `DoctorType` . Where/how is DoctorType defined?

Comment: Because my DrType is a string

Comment: Are you trying to set up an implicit conversion from `std::string` to `DoctorType` ?

Comment: @MarcoMoctezumaMartinez you're not showing us where you defined the type

Comment: @MarcoMoctezumaMartinez then show how you define `DoctorType`

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, I would like to do a conversion. I want to be able to access my mutators from my DoctorType.

Comment: @t.niese i added the DoctorType.  Is that more helpful?

Comment: In the shown code there is nothing that would allow the compiler to convert `std::string`  to `DoctorType`, so why do you expect that it should be possible?  With the shown code I my self would not even know how `DoctorType` can be constructed, because `DoctorType` has no  constructor and `PersonType` is not known to me. But still, as `DoctorType` is not a string, why do you thing that the compiler should be able to convert a `std::string` to `DoctorType`?

Comment: @t.niese Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

`void PatientType::setDrName(DoctorType drName)`

Here, you expect to send a `DoctorType` parameter. However, in calling you use:

`example.setDrName(drName);` where `drName` is a `string`, not a `DoctorType` parameter.

The fix is obvious: either modify the prototype so as it accepts a `string` parameter or, in calling the method, give it a `DoctorType` parameter.

Comment: I changed the variable string drName; to DoctorType drName;  As a result I get this error "No viable overloaded '=' "  When you say give DoctorType a parameter are you referring to something like DoctorType(string)? @bogdan Doicin

Comment: @MarcoMoctezumaMartinez Try Option 2 in my answer. It should work for you.

Comment: Yes. The error message you received was because `DoctorType` is not a simple type, like `string`, is a structured type, a `class`. If you choose this path, please make the appropriate modifications.

Comment: @KunalPuri yeah, it's simpler than option 1.

Comment: What is the "simple type" you are referring to? Both `std::string` and `DoctorType` are simple classes (ok, string is a typedef, but the point still holds).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this function:

```
void PatientType::setDrName(DoctorType drName) {
```

Here, this function expects parameter of type DoctorType but you are passing std::string.

```
example.setDrName(drName); // drName is std::string. So, Type mismatch
```

There are numerous ways to solve this:

Option 1: Change the function signature to `void PatientType::setDrName(const std::string &drName) {`

Option 2: Less trivial but it works. Define a parameterised constructor in `DoctorType` accepting `std::string` as parameter.

Like this:

```
DoctorType::DoctorType(const std::string &name): name(name) { }
```

I think Option 2 is suitable in your scenario.

As rightly suggested by [@t.niese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1960455/t-niese), you must explicitly create the object of DoctorType and define constructor as explicit. Like this:

```
explicit DoctorType::DoctorType(const std::string &name): name(name) { }
```

and while calling it:

```
example.setDrName(DoctorType(drName));
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix it with "explicit DoctorTyp..."

Comment: @MarcoMoctezumaMartinez If you feel that this answered your question, please consider voting and accepting https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers